# Conversion from XSLT 1.0 to 2.0 doesn't give first text from a tag

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I am trying to use XSLT 2.0, however, the tag `<xsl:value-of select=...>` doesn't give me the first element anymore. I get all the values in the XML. How can I convert the following XSLT to work with XSLT 2.0?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Data/ABC">
        <xsl:for-each select=".">
            <Data xmlns="example.com">
                <GEF>
                    <id><xsl:value-of select="id"/></id>
                    <time><xsl:value-of select="time"/></time>
                    <type>test</type>
                </GEF>
            </Data>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I had this XML:

```
<Data xmlns="example.com">
    <ABC>
        <id>2</id>
        <time>125622</time>
    </ABC>
</Data>
```

If I was using XSLT 1.0, I would get this:

```
<Data xmlns="example.com">
    <GEF>
        <id>2</id>
        <time>125622</time>
        <type>test</type>
    </GEF>
</Data>
```

Usually, I would get `2` and `125622` as single items for each tag in the XSLT. However, Now it just gets both of the values and outputs them. It doesn't even print the tags after the transformation. What am I suppose to use in 2.0? My searching didn't bring anything up.

This is what I get with 2.0:

```
<Data xmlns="example.com">

  2
  125622
  test

</Data>
```

Comment: What is the result you want to get? -- And why do you have `<xsl:apply-templates mode="DataRsp"/>` but no templates in that mode?

Comment: "Now it just gets both of the values and outputs them. It doesn't even print the tags after the transformation" sounds as if the elements in your input XML are in a namespace and therefore your templates are not applied. Is there any `xmlns="..."` on the `Data` element or an ancestor?

Comment: Your second template match should be `match="ABC"`. Because you overqualify the match, only the default transformation rules are applied, namely to emit just the text of the elements. Remove `Data/` and it should work.

Comment: Sorry, left out the namespace by mistake. @michael.hor257k I do have a template for that, just didn't paste it. I'll edit the OP.

Comment: How did you run the XSLT with XSLT 1.0? Any chance you build a not namespace aware DOM tree and the processor therefore ignored the `xmlns="example.com"`?

Comment: @BobDalgleish I took `Data/` out, but still get the same result (posted to op). @Martin Honnen I ran it with some Java code using the `Document` and `Transformer` classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT and XPath (1.0 as later versions) work with a namespace aware data model, so given `<Data xmlns="example.com">` the `Data` element and its descendants are in the namespace `example.com` and your XSLT needs to take that into account. In XSLT 2.0 you can do that with

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xpath-default-namespace="example.com">
```

As for your Java code, make sure you use a [namespace aware DocumentBuilderFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html).

Comment: Thank you. I sort of get the output I want. It now prints how it should. However, under the last `</Data>`, it prints out all the text values as well. In addition, `<xsl:param name="sheet-uri" select="some.xml"/> <xsl:param name="sheet-doc" select="document($sheet-uri)"/>` is not working anymore (worked fine with 1.0). Any idea on why that may be? Again thank you very much for the help!

Comment: As for the text values printed out as well, I would expect that to happen for the first version of the code that used a mode but did not have any explicit template in that mode.  For the param problem I think you should ask a new question, `<xsl:param name="sheet-uri" select="some.xml"/>` certainly looks wrong and would need to be `<xsl:param name="sheet-uri" select="'some.xml'"/>`. But relative URIs can be a problem, please ask a new question with all necessary details of XSLT and Java code.

Comment: I do have templates defined for the modes I have listed in my XSLT. So there is no mode that is not being used. Is it because of this line: `  <xsl:apply-templates/>`? Thought that was used for templates that don't have modes. And I'll make a new question for the other problem.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get your code to work under XSLT 2.0 is to run it under backwards compatibility mode, which you can do simply by leaving the version number as version="1.0". If you know that the dependency on XSLT 1.0 semantics only applies to particular parts of the stylesheet then you can do this selectively, for example

```
         <xsl:for-each select="." version="1.0">
            <Data xmlns="example.com">
                <GEF>
                    <id><xsl:value-of select="id"/></id>
                    <time><xsl:value-of select="time"/></time>
                    <type>test</type>
                </GEF>
            </Data>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

If you can, though, it's best to convert the code to work the 2.0 way. If you only want an `xsl:value-of` instruction to process the first item in a node-set, just add `[1]` to select the first item, for example

```
<id><xsl:value-of select="id[1]"/></id>
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice to know I can do it this way as well.